# Underline Function?

Tags: discussion

Simple question:

Why is it that the response / question boxes have **bold** and *italic* functions, but no underline functions?

It's kind of a standard, basic thing right?

Comment: +1 Good thing to ask, even though the answer is "negative".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's just a "web thing".  Underlined text normally means a link while you're on the Internet, and violating that user expectation is A Bad Thing™.  I was also taught not to use it in formal writing except for perhaps headings and such — supposedly if you really really have to emphasize something, you're supposed to use italics (bold at worst).  (And while most browsers support `<u>`, it's deprecated and crappy.)

As usual I type up an answer and then go look for an official one ... [turns out I'm right about the reasonings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117018/154510) :P

Comment: Yes, I was just about to write my own answer when I followed that link. My usual explanation is that underline only exists because typewriters couldn't italicize.

Comment: That makes sense - I completely forgot about that rule of user expectation! Thanks!